# Do I need to escape my data values when I pass them to prepared SQL statements?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, prepared-statement, sql-injection

When I use prepared statements do I have to use functions like `mysqli_real_escape_string` or are the executed automatically?

For example should I just use this

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt->bindParam('sd', $name, $value);
```

or do I have to use something like this

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt->bindParam('sd', mysqli_real_escape_string($name), mysqli_real_escape_string($value));
```

Which functions are recommended to avoid sql injections?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you do not need to escape your parameters.  In fact, escaping variables that you then pass in to a parametrized query is an error and will give you incorrect results.

Answer (score 2):

When using parameterized queries, the escaping is done by the API.  your first method is correct.

If you are doing raw text queries, then you should escape your parameter values.

Answer (score 1):

Prepared statements automatically scrub what you're inserting. When you do the following:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (:name, :value)");
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt->bindParam(':value', $value);
```

That bindParam function is doing all the necessary cleaning for you and then inserting that value into the query string.

Fun fact, prepared statements are a hack built on top of a hack in their fundamental idea :)